# mysql with php joining and searching

Tags: php, mysql, search, join

I have three table in MySQL named as `users`, `user_academic_info`, `department_info` and I want to get a joining result on these three to get a search like option. The query is as below:

```
SELECT full_name, user_id, email, mobile, dept_name
FROM users, department_info
WHERE dept_id = (select dept_id from user_academic_info where ainfo_id = user_id)
AND full_name LIKE '%%'
OR user_id LIKE '%%'
OR email LIKE '%%'
OR mobile LIKE '%%'
OR dept_name LIKE '%%'
```

It shows me all the users with all the departments where as in database they are belong to only a single department.

Answer (score 0):

see [mysql join](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/join.html)

```
SELECT * FROM `users` AS `u`
LEFT JOIN `user_academic_info` AS `ui` ON (
   `u`.`id` = `ui`.`user_id`
)
LEFT JOIN `department_info` AS `di` ON (
   `di`.`dept_id` =`ui`.`dept_id`
)
WHERE `u`.`full_name` LIKE '%%'
OR `u`.`id` = 4
```

The above query should get you all the fields from all 3 tables.
Add your WHERE clause and prefix the fields with the correct table name.

Comment: i get all the fields but i want to perform a search operation so i have used like multiple times

Comment: Once you have all field you can add your WHERE clause like before.. just add the table alias before the field